# Is it possible to define your own Persistent / Esqueleto lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, haskell-persistent

Given the following persistent type:

```
share
    [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    [persistLowerCase|
Account
    email Text
    passphrase Text
    firstName Text
    lastName Text
    deriving Eq Show Generic
|]
```

What I think is a kind of lens is generated, ie `AccountEmail`, `AccountPassphrase` etc etc. Is it possible to combine these in such a way, not necessarily composition but say string concatenation, I often find myself writing these kinds of functions:

```
accountFullName :: SqlExpr (Entity Account) -> SqlExpr Text
accountFullName acc = acc ^. AccountFirstName ++. val " " ++. acc ^. AccountLastName
```

It would be good if I could define this in a similar way to `Account*` so I can call them using `^.` rather than using raw functions, ie `acc ^. AccountFullName`. This may not be an appropriate way of using these accessors, but if it isn't I would be interested to know why as I feel it may help further my understanding of this part of the Persistent library, as I feel fairly lost when I look at the code around `EntityField`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible.

```
(^.) :: (PersistEntity val, PersistField typ)
     => expr (Entity val)
     -> EntityField val typ
     -> expr (Value typ)
```

You'll see that the second argument is `EntityField val typ`, which is a type family defined in the `PersistEntity val` class. This is pre-defined for your table, and can't be changed, so this particular operator can't be used for custom accessors the way you want.

---

When you use `persistLowerCase` and friends, it uses Template Haskell to parse your definition and generate appropriate data definitions. As I understand it, something similar to the following is generated:

```
data Account = Account
  { accountEmail :: Text
  , accountPassphrase :: Text
  , accountFirstName :: Text
  , accountLastName :: Text
  }

data AccountField a where
  AccountId :: AccountField Key
  AccountEmail :: AccountField Text
  AccountPassphrase :: AccountField Text
  AccountFirstName :: AccountField Text
  AccountLastName :: AccountField Text

instance PersistEntity Account where
  data EntityField Account a = AccountField a
  ...
```

(This isn't syntactically accurate and is missing a lot of detail, but it provides enough context for this situation I think.)

So the "lens" you pass to `(^.)` is actually just a constructor for a type associated with your table type `Account`. You can't create new constructors or re-associate the type family dynamically, so you can't make something else that can be passed to `(^.)`. These accessors are effectively set in stone.

---

I think it makes the most sense to just go with the raw function. `accountFullName acc` isn't bad to write, and it makes it clear that you're doing something a little more complex than just pulling a field value.